# How to change div values without ID or class

Tags: css

How do I change the value of DIV if it has no ID or class? here's a sample code:

```
<div id=1>
   <div id=2>
     <div id=3>
        <div id=4>
            <div><span>div without id or class</span></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many ways.  One way is to use a CSS selector with jQuery.

Comment: You can also use the CSS3 `content` property, but it only works on the `:before` and `:after` properties. https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the div id="4", you can do something like.

```
document.getElementById('4').firstElementChild.innerHtml = 'stuff you want to change to'
```

If you don't know, and you're a bit masochistic and don't want to use jquery, you can use a combination of `.firstChild` `.nextSibling` to walk your way to the div with the desired set of stuffs.